# Как сделать пагинацию в Entity Framework Core и API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Есть поисковой запрос,который выводит значения из базы данных. Проблема в том,что вхождений может быть огромное количество и поэтому хочу сделать пагинацию. Вопрос в том,как это реализовать, если не знаешь сколько тебе выведет вхождений.Пока имею только такой поверхностный код.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/search/{searchform}")]
public ActionResult Search(string searchform)
{
    var search = _context.SlideDb.Where(p => p.TextSlide.Contains(searchform));
    var dataPag = search.Take(30);
    var dataPag2 = search.Skip(30).Take(30);
    return Ok(dataPag);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так обычно и делается и в самоделках и пакетах типа PagedList (поковыряйте их исходники: они оба есть на гитхабе - и старый и core'овский), почитайте например [на метаните](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/17.7.php).

И претензии в общем-то одинаковые - что работает это не очень эффективно по скорости, поищите статьи на хабре, (например, [вот тут рекомендуют использовать лямбды](https://habr.com/post/269901/#2b)) там разбирались вопросы почему Skip+Take проигрывает raw sql.

Ну и до кучи, не знаю, это у вас заготовка и опущены важные подробности, но вы не используете `.AsNoTracking()` - и выключив отслеживание изменений вы можете получить прирост до 10% (цифра из очень старого отчёта майкрософт по EF5, новых не видел).

Comment: Уточните к какому из методов надо добавить `.AsNoTracking()`

Comment: @4per В конце запроса непосредственно перед материализацией запроса (перед .ToList, .ToArray и т.п.)